# Log in in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having some trouble with my application, because I need 2 ways to log in: form (user + password) or route (passing user unique identifier).

I configured FormsAuthentication and it's working for user + password method, but when I try to log in through unique identifier, I can't redirect to my HomeController.

User + Password:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Authenticate(string usuario, string senha, string returnUrl)
    {
        var authenticated = this.UsuarioService.Acessar(usuario, senha, out int codUsuario);

        if (authenticated)
        {
            var user = this.UsuarioService.Buscar(codUsuario);

            MontaPermissoes(ref user);

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user), false);

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                return returnUrl;
            else
                return Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = "" });
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Unique Identifier:

```
    [HttpGet]
    private RedirectToRouteResult Autenticacao(Guid uniqId)
    {
        var usuario = UsuarioService.Buscar(uniqId);

        if (usuario != null)
        {
            MontaPermissoes(ref usuario);

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usuario), false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { culture = RouteData.Values["culture"] });
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", new { culture = RouteData.Values["culture"] });
    }
```

Using user + password, I just return next URL to redirect via Javascript, but unique identifier log in will be used by another application, using the same database.

Comment: What happens if you try to log in with the uniqId, does it redirect to the FormsAuthentication login page ?

Comment: Exactly! It doesn't redirect or log in (IsAuthenticated is always false).

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be IIS related, your application has to have two authentication options enabled.

- FormsAuthentication
- Anonymous Authentication

With anonymous authentication enabled the application can allow Anonymous calls.

You can add an AllowAnonymous attribute to your controller or specific controller methods to make sure that FormsAuthentication won't be triggered.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class MyController: Controller {}
```